# Adjective for the likes of someone who consistently has a hard time finishing what s/he has started?

Tags: adjectives, expressions

What adjective would you suggest for the like of someone who consistently has a hard time finishing what s/he has started?

I thought of the word "distracted", but I don't feel it's sufficient to describe the full story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak-willed looks appropriate here. Irresolute may also fit. Irresolute is more about changing his mind and not making choices while weak-willed describes literally a lack of will.

Answer (score 3):

*Feckless* may come close: ‘lacking vigour, energy, or capacity’.

Answer (score 2):

- *[Procrastinator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/procrastinator)*, One who procrastinates; one who delays working on things.
- *butterfly*, in sense of flitting from flower to flower
- A *dabbler* or *[dilettante](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilettante)* need not be a *non-finisher*, but often may be.
- A couple of neologisms from *[tardy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tardy)* (late; overdue or delayed; ineffectual) and *[dilatory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilatory)* (intentionally delaying ..., intended to cause delay) are the horrid *tardian* and nicer *dilatorian*, which may carry a soupçon of humor.

Answer (score 1):

"**infirm of purpose**"
lacking firmness of will or character or purpose

"*infirm of purpose; give me the daggers*" - Shakespeare

However, this term may also mean lacking a definite objective or purpose altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The colloquial *sticktoitiveness* is a good antonym for your situation.  So perhaps what you need is "xxx lacks any sticktoitiveness."